# SQL Query left join not filtering data

Tags: sql, database

This is my query

```
SELECT 
     tblDiseases.disease
FROM
     tblRel 
LEFT JOIN 
     tblDiseases ON tblRel.diseaseID = tblDiseases.diseaseID
WHERE 
     tblRel.symptomID = '1' AND tblRel.symptomID = '2' AND tblRel.symptomID = '3'
```

and here are my tables

```
#tblDiseases - holds all disease names
######################################
diseaseID | disease     
-----------------------
 1            Tifoyd        
 2            Jondis    
 3            Malarya
 4            Pneomonia
 5            Dengu


 #tblSymptoms - holds all symptoms
 #################################
symptomID | symptom
-------------------------
1            Headache        
2            Temparature    
3            Less Pain
4            Sever Pain
5            Mussle Pain


 #tblRel - holds relation between diseases and symptoms
 ######################################################
 relID  | dieaseID | symptomID
 -----------------------------
 1         1          1
 2         1          2
 3         3          1
 4         3          2
 5         3          3
```

I have selected the disease with symptoms "headache" "temperature" and "less pain" so it should give "Malarya" but instead it gives nothing.

Comment: AND is problem. Change it for OR.

Answer (score 0):

A single column in a single row cannot have three different values.  What you want is aggregation, to compare values in different rows:

```
SELECT d.disease
FROM tblRel r JOIN
     tblDiseases d
     ON r.diseaseID = d.diseaseID
WHERE r.symptomID IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY d.disease
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3;  -- has all three symptoms
```

Note that `LEFT JOIN` is not necessary, because you need a match to name the disease.  (Presumably, the disease ids match between the tables, as they would in a well-formed database.)